# How is InitialTargets chained when doing Import on an msbuild file?

Tags: msbuild

When I have an msbuild file `foo.csproj` and I want to `Import` a shared `proj`/`targets` file, how is the [`Project.InitialTargets`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.project.initialtargets.aspx) attribute *supposed* (i.e. officially) to behave?

What I see with testing MSBUILD 2.0 and 4.x is that, given the following:

```
<Project InitialTargets="TestMain" ...>
  ...
  <Import Project="Sub.targets"/>
  ...
  <Target Name="TestMain">
    <Message Text="Hello from Main" />
  </Target>
```

and

```
<Project InitialTargets="TestSubInit" ...>
  ...
  <Target Name="TestSubInit">
    <Message Text="Hello from sub.targets" />
  </Target>
```

then the `InitalTargets` are chained in order of inclusion, i.e. first the output is:

```
TestMain-Target:
    Hello from Main
TestSubInit-Target:
    Hello from sub.targets
```

I want to rely on this chaining behavior - is this documented somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chaining behaviour for the `InitialTargets` attribute is documented on the MSDN page for the [`<Project>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/project-element-msbuild) element.

From the documentation:

> If multiple imported files define InitialTargets, all targets
>   mentioned will be run, in the order the imports are encountered.

So, the ordering that you see seems to be documented.

---

Furthermore, the docs for the [`Import` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019) state:

> If the imported project does not have a `DefaultTargets` attribute,
>   imported projects are inspected in the order that they are imported,
>   ... . For example, if **ProjectA imports** ProjectB and ProjectC (in that
>   order), and ProjectB imports ProjectD, MSBuild **first looks** for
>   DefaultTargets specified **on ProjectA, then ProjectB**, then ProjectD,
>   and finally ProjectC.

While this talks about the `DefaultTargets` attribute, it is a hint that the `*Targets` Attributes are treated in-order starting at the "main/"importing" project, so

> ... in the order the imports are encountered

would then mean that the "main" file is just put at the start of the "imports" list. (Which is what is observed.)